# Bind Caliburn Micro to EF Entity Error

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm binding an Entity Framework 6.0 Entity to a Caliburn Micro View:

```
<aura:AuditView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="SelectedAudit" cal:View.Model="{Binding SelectedAudit}" cal:View.Context="SelectedAudit"/>
```

The error produced on screen is:

```
"Cannot find view for System.Data.Entity.DynamicProcies.Audit_9B5A..."
```

`SelectedAudit` is the entity property on the ViewModel. Should I create a map (AutoMapper) from + to entity to a new `AuditModel`? Or am I missing something magical?

**EDIT:** code for `aura:AuditView`

```
<UserControl x:Class="Aura.AuditView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:aura="clr-namespace:Aura"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="LockedTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEFE2E2"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Description" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="3" />

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="User" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding UserId}" Margin="3" Style="{StaticResource LockedTextBox}"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Begin date" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <DatePicker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" SelectedDate="{Binding BeginDate}" Margin="3"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Deadline" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <DatePicker Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" SelectedDate="{Binding Deadline}" Margin="3"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="End date" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding EndDate, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}" Margin="3" Style="{StaticResource LockedTextBox}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what the question is? Please try to state the problem more clearly.

Comment: Not sure what's going on either - are you expecting the `View.Context` binding to pick up views from the "SelectedAudit" namespace? Did you mean to bind `View.Context` to a property on `SelectedAudit`? Are you using a composition that is supposed to dynamically resolve the view for the selected audit?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to bind SelectedAudit to shared:AuditView

Comment: I assume you want it to be view-first and not view-model first?

Comment: I don't believe you need the `View.Context` binding then - (since you already have your view and you haven't bound it, it looks like it's set to a constant), can you post the XAML for the `shared:AuditView` as I believe your issue is contained within

Answer (score 0):

I believe you actually want

`cal:Bind.Model="{Binding SelectedAudit}"`

Otherwise you are trying to do viewmodel-first resolution in which case Caliburn Micro will look to resolve a view for the VM instead of using the view that you have provided.

e.g.

`<aura:AuditView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="SelectedAudit" cal:Bind.Model="{Binding SelectedAudit}" />`

Comment: Hi, I just tried this. Same problem occured. I'm trying AutoMapper but feel free to expand your answer! ^^